# Why does a user receive a "permission denied" error when trying to update their user password in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql-12

I have several users of our PostgreSQL (12) database who are not superusers. From the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-alterrole.html), it would appear that any "ordinary" user should be able to set their password to something new, via:

```
ALTER ROLE [user] WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '[new password]' VALID UNTIL '2021-11-30'
```

However, when a non-superuser tries this, they receive a "permission denied" error.

For context, we would like to have database users update their passwords once every 3 months, for security purposes.

Comment: I don't think a regular user is allowed to change the `valid until` option.

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name -- thank you! It appears you're correct. The users can indeed set passwords, but cannot apply the VALID UNTIL option. Would you like to add this as a documented answer, so I can award you the bounty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regular user can not set the `valid until` option.

And if you think about it, it wouldn't make sense, as the user then could choose a much longer period.